# ruby sidekiq `require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sidekiq

I try to build a microservice on pure ruby with some additional features. I use [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) for jobs and [pg](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg) for DB connection.

To start the Sidekiq server I use default settings and code:

```
# ./config/sidekiq.rb

require 'sidekiq'
require 'pg'  # This doesn't work with "`require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)"
require_relative '../jobs/location_jobs/collect_job' # here is my job locates

# If your client is single-threaded, we just need a single connection in our Redis connection pool
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: 'analytic_serv', size: 5 }
end

# Sidekiq server is multi-threaded so our Redis connection pool size defaults to concurrency (-c)
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: 'analytic_serv' }
end
```

As you can see I try `require` PG gem in `sidekiq.rb`. Actually I use it in another file and use it here only for example.

**So, when I try to run my sidekiq-server it raises an exception**

```
bundle exec sidekiq -r ./config/sidekiq.rb -C ./config/sidekiq.yml
```

`analytic_serv/config/sidekiq.rb:2:in` require': cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)`

**it works for the simple ruby script that I use for creating job, but it doesn't work when I run sidekiq-server.**

Please, help. *What am I doing wrong?*
**How can I include a gem in this case?**

Comment: Are you sure the `pg` gem is installed on the machine?

Comment: sure! I use it for set data, when I create job. And with my other Rails projects

Comment: it works in ruby script, but not in sidekiq-server file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `gem 'pg'` to your `Gemfile`, and install bundle via `bundle install`.

Answer (score 3):

Always use Bundler to make sure your gems are set up correctly: `bundle exec ruby script.rb` and `bundle exec sidekiq`

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot load such a file means, the specific file is not available.
Search for path `bundle show pg`.

Sometimes even if the gem is not there it is shown because of the **gemspec**. So, remove the **gemspec** as well and do `bundle install`.